# Loading new page after php code has run?

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I have a form, this form is on a page called question1.php, and I want it to load question2.php when the submit button is pressed.

```
<form action="question2.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="cuboid">
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="cone">
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="cylinder">
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="sphere">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

But I also have this php code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      if(isset( $_POST['ans'])) {
           $selected_answer = $_POST['ans'];
           if($selected_answer == "cuboid") {
               $_SESSION["cuboid"] = ((int)$_SESSION["cuboid"]) + 1;
           }
      }
    }
?>
```

EDIT: I have made a simpler demo to try and explain myself better, i have got three pages.

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="page2.php">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="page3.php" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="ans" value="color">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['ans'])) {
        $selected_answer = $_POST['ans'];
        if($selected_answer == "color") {
            $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "red";
        }
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And page3.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
     echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

So on the first page I declare the session variable "favcolor", then on the second page if the user selects the radio button I want to update the color to red, however it just won't chane for me, on the third page it is still printing green

Comment: you probably forget `session_start()`. no started session, no preserved/propagated data

Comment: What?? You should really read more about what php really is on http://php.net

Comment: I have got session_start(), At the end of my quiz (5 questions) I can display the session variable however they have not been incremented when they should be

Comment: ^ they always say that "after the fact".

Comment: What you may be looking for is an ajax function in your submit.

Comment: You've shown us 1 html form and 1 php/sessions piece of code for 1 file. I am suspecting that you're not showing us the full picture here, and you most probable unknown "next page for the session" isn't being passed there. Tell me I'm right on this one. Oh and you're also doing nothing in that PHP, far as I can see. You're just declaring stuff.

Comment: *"I have got session_start(), At the end of my quiz (5 questions)"* - "at the end?"......... I am out of this question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are right I do not have all the code here, but the code of all 5 of my pages is almost identical, all I want the php to do is increase the "cuboid" variable by 1 if the "cuboid" radio button is selected

Comment: btw for a session to be used effectively it must be before any session variables are set  check out the examples here http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Can you show us your full code? Then we can better assist you. Much like Fred says, it's difficult to see the issue with the data you've given us currently :)

Comment: No I have session_start on all my pages

Comment: At the top of all of your pages? Before anything else?

Comment: Yes very first thing on each page

Comment: Could everyone please take a look at my edit I have tried to explain myself better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had issue on page2.php because you are submitting form on page3.php but you are handling submission request on page2.php. So i corrected below for you.

page1.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="page2.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="page3.php" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="ans" value="color">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>        
 </body>
</html>
```

page3.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
    <?php
    // Echo session variables that were set on previous page
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['ans'])) {
            $selected_answer = $_POST['ans'];
            if ($selected_answer == "color") {
                $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "red";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".";
    ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should work.

```
$_SESSION["cuboid"] = isset($_SESSION["cuboid"]) ? $_SESSION["cuboid"] : 0;
$_SESSION["cuboid"] = ((int)$_SESSION["cuboid"]) + 1;
```

Comment: Why would you only hope?

Comment: Could you please take a look at my edit I have tried to explain myself better :)

Comment: Look my latest answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you are attempting to redirect to another webpage.

Try sending HTTP headers using the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

```
header('Location: http://example.com/page3.php');
exit();
```

If the HTTP header doesn't work at first, turn on the output buffer using [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for $_POST['ans'] in the wrong page.

Currently you are checking for 'ans' when user enters page2.php, which is before the user submits the form that contains that input element.

When you submit the form on page2.php, the action sends the request over to page3.php, so you actually want to move your if statement that sets the color to green to the top (below session start) of page3.php